# Can I connect any custom domain to Firebase Hosting?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

On Firebase Hosting docs it says that you can connect [www.example.com](http://www.example.com). I could not find there if you can connect .org, .net, .ru etc. Does anybody know if you can connect any other custom domains to firebase hosting?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter what the domain is called.  The [instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain) are always the same.